# Why Ridge regularization has the grouping effect

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

I want to use elastic net (lasso + ridge) method for feature selection process. I can't understand why does the ridge method gives me the grouping effect for correlated variables. Can anyone explain that please?

Comment: @kjetil Thank you I think that the explanation in that post sums it up pretty nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The L1 norm tends to overfit [the most contributory $X_i$ variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization). With ridge regression a bias is added that can reduce the [propagated error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example) of a parameter of interest, for example, see [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10928-010-9167-z). Alternatively, [ridge regression can be used to reduce covariance](http://math.arizona.edu/~hzhang/math574m/Read/Ridge.pdf) if one uses a [smoothing factor](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/sta305files/Rudyregularization.pdf) appropriate to that task.